# Inject HttpContext in ASP.Net 5

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to inject HttpContext into my controller's constructor. Anyone knows how to configure it in ConfigureServices()?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Injecting `HttpContext` directly in your dependencies is not the recommended approach. Instead, you should use `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```
public class MyComponent : IMyComponent {
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;

    public MyComponent(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
        this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public string GetDataFromSession() {
        return contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString(*KEY*);
    }
}
```

That said, it's usually not needed in a controller, where you can easily retrieve the current `HttpContext` using the `Context` property.

Of course, due to the way controllers are created, this property is unavailable when you instantiate a controller, so don't try to access it from the constructor. In this case, try to refactor your code to avoid accessing `HttpContext` there or use `IHttpContextAccessor` as a replacement.